# HP Elitebook 8470P Power 65 watt or 90 watt

Tags: laptop, adapter, smps

I have an HP Elitebook 8470P. It does a lot of heavy SQL Work. I was running it with 65 Watt 18.5V 3.5A Power Adapter which came with it. It overheated and burst a couple of days back after using it for around 2 years. Thankfully Laptop is safe.

I checked https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c03374369#AbT7 and it lists two types of power adapters. 90 watt 19V 4.74A Discrete Config and 65 Watt 18.5V 3.5A UMA Config (the one which I was using). Is it possible that it burst because of excessive workload. If so, Should I buy the one with 90 watt power this time around whihc might also help my batch run faster.

Also I have a 65 watt 19.5V 3.33A adapter lying around with me with matching connector size. Can I use it instead without risk of frying the laptop. The wattage is same 65 Watt but Voltage and Current is different.